# How do I access this JSON data using D3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am aware that loading JSON in D3 is done like so and this does not produce any errors:

```
d3.json("sample_data/unique_items.json", function(json) {
  // do something
});
```

Inside this block, I then reference the json file using the `json` variable. Here is the sample structure of the JSON:

```
{
  "unique_items": [
    {
      "name": "Blah",
      "items": [
        {"id": 1, "note": "blah"},
        {"id": 2, "note": "blah blah"},
        {"id": 3, "note": "blah blah blah"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Blah2",
      "items": [
        {"id": 1, "note": "blah"},
        {"id": 2, "note": "blah blah"},
        {"id": 3, "note": "blah blah blah"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm struggling with how to access items in this structure. So for instance I tried this as a test:

```
for (var item in json["unique_items"]) {
  if (json["unique_items"].hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    console.log(item["name"]);  // 'undefined' error on this line
  }
}
```

I get an undefined error on the line commented as such above. I would expect to see this in the console:

```
Blah
Blah2
```

I tried changing that line to `console.log(item.name);` but that produced the same error. I then changed the line to simply `console.log(item);` and the output to the console was `0`. I don't understand this.

So my questions are:

1. How do I access elements within `unique_items`?
2. Is there a better way the json should be structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
for (var key in json["unique_items"]) {
  var item = json["unique_items"][key];
  if (item) {
    console.log(item["name"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: That solved it! I see what happened then. The first iteration just gets its index/position in the array (0), and then I still need to use that to access that item by its index within the array. Thank you!

Comment: you had the right idea if you used for .. of .. instead of for .. in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of